# How to specify git to only ignore files that match a pattern and not a directory?

Tags: git, directory, gitignore

I ran into a scenario today where there was a naming collision with a file we desire to ignore and a sub directory in one of our projects. In a new project that is being set up on git, there is a directory called `src/core/app`. Our default git ignore excludes any file called `core` due to it being output if there is a core dump. The `.gitignore` file contains a similar line like so:

```
#debug files
core
```

We worked around it by doing a `git add -f`,  but I'm curious is there an available git ignore syntax that would specify we only want  to ignore a file named core and not include any directories that may be named `core`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is actually possible using negative patterns and a trailing slash (which matches directories). Put these two lines in your `.gitignore`:

```
core
!core/
```

This will ignore files named `core` but not directories named `core`.